# Sails.js Model relationship

Tags: sails.js, relationship

I am trying to come up with what type of relationship this is for a simple card game.

My models are `Game`, `Player`, and `Card`.

My card game is defined by a pre determinted deck (think like poker).

Does a player have many cards through games? Or do I need a join table like "Deck" or "Hand" in order to store this properly?